# Move semantics in Rust

Tags: rust, move-semantics, ffi, dangling-pointer

I'm wrapping a C library in Rust, and many of its functions take parameters by pointers to structs, which themselves often have pointers to other structs.  In the interest of reducing overhead, I'd like to provide the ability to cache the results of marshaling the Rust data into the C structs.

Here's an example of how the C library might expect some parameters:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    x: i32,
    y: f32
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Bar {
    p_foo: *const Foo,
    z: bool
}
```

And how I'd imagine an owning, "cached" version would look:

```
struct Cached {
    foo: Option<Foo>,
    bar: Bar
}
```

The `p_foo` field of `bar` would be constructed to point to `Some` value within `foo`, or a null pointer if there was `None`.

The issue, here, of course, is that if a value of `Cached` was to be moved, a straight `memcpy` would be inappropriate and `bar.p_foo` would additionally need to be redirected.  This would be easy to ensure in C++, with its definable move semantics, but does Rust offer a solution besides "don't set `bar.p_foo` until it's used"?  While it would certainly work to do it that way, I don't imagine that these cached values will be moved more than (or even close to the frequency that) they are reused, and there is a bit of work involved to set up these pointers, especially if the nesting/chaining is deep/long.  I'd also rather not `Box` the substructures up on the heap.

---

To clarify, here's what I can write in C++, which I would like to replicate in Rust:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    float y;
};

struct Bar {
    Foo const*pFoo;
    bool z;
};

// bear with me while I conjure up a Maybe for C++
class Cached {
public:
    // would have appropriate copy constructor/assignment

    Cached(Cached &&other) {
        m_foo = other.m_foo;
        m_bar = other.m_bar;

        if(m_foo.isJust()) {
            m_bar.pFoo = &m_foo.value();
        } // else already nullptr
    }

    // similar move assignment

private:
    Maybe<Foo> m_foo;
    Bar m_bar;
};
```

Comment: *is that if a value of `Cached` was to be moved* - I feel like you aren't providing enough information. What would be keeping a pointer to `bar.p_foo` that would be invalidated when it's moved? Does something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=53bf026d76e0665e2381&version=stable) seem useful at all?

Comment: `bar.p_foo` *is* the pointer that would be invalidated if the object was to be moved, as it points to a (part of a) field of the structure itself.  I'll clarify by writing the equivalent to what I want in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The Rust-equivalent would be to not use raw pointers, as raw pointers are there for implementing our safe datastructures, not for implementing normal datastructures.

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    x: i32,
    y: f32
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Bar {
    p_foo: Option<Box<Foo>>,
    z: bool
}
```

An `Option<Box<T>>` is guaranteed to be exactly equivalent (in bits in memory) to a `*const T`, as long as `T` is a type and not a trait. The only difference is that it's safe to use within Rust.

This way you don't even need a `Cached` struct anymore, but can directly pass around the `Bar` object.

---

> I'd also rather not Box the substructures up on the heap.

Then I suggest you don't keep a `Bar` object around, and instead conjure it up whenever you need to pass one to C:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    x: i32,
    y: f32
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Bar<'a> {
    p_foo: Option<&'a Foo>,
    z: bool
}

struct Cached {
    foo: Option<Foo>,
    z: bool,
}

impl Cached {
    fn bar<'a>(&'a self) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar {
            p_foo: self.foo.as_ref(),
            z: self.z,
        }
    }
}
```

> there is a bit of work involved to set up these pointers, especially if the nesting/chaining is deep/long.

That sounds a lot like premature optimization. Don't optimize where you haven't benchmarked.